# ¿Cómo reemplazar un texto y un botón en html con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código y mi objetivo es:

- Inicialmente quiero mostrar solo el Texto 1 y el botón 1
- Al pulsar el botón 1 con el texto `Mostrar texto 2`, me oculte el Texto 1 y el botón 1 y me muestre el Texto 2 y el botón 2 y asi sucesívamente.

¿Pueden ayudarme? Gracias!!

```js
function muestra1(){
  document.getElementById('bloque1').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('bloque2').style.display="none";
};

function muestra2(){
  document.getElementById('bloque1').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('bloque2').style.display="block";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>

 <body>

  <h3>Cambiar texto y botón</h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="bloque1">Texto 1
   <input type="button" value="Mostrar texto 2" onclick="muestra2();">
  </div>

  <div class="bloque2">Texto 2
   <input type="button" value="Mostrar texto 1" onclick="muestra1();">
  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al buscar por Id, los bloques tienen que tener el id informado. Si no, nunca lo encontrarás.

Si quieres que desde el inicio sólo se muestre uno, puedes dejar la propiedad `style="display:none"` informada desde el principio en el bloque 2

```js
function muestra1(){
  document.getElementById('bloque1').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('bloque2').style.display="none";
};

function muestra2(){
  document.getElementById('bloque1').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('bloque2').style.display="block";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>

 <body>

  <h3>Cambiar texto y botón</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="bloque1" class="bloque1">Texto 1
   <input type="button" value="Mostrar texto 2" onclick="muestra2();">
  </div>
  <div style="display:none" id="bloque2" class="bloque2">Texto 2
   <input type="button" value="Mostrar texto 1" onclick="muestra1();">
  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente que estás tratando de obtener un elemento por medio de su `id` pero este no esta declarado como atributo de tu etiqueta HTML.

Por lo anterior entonces te dará error de:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Entonces lo que debes hacer es colocarlo como *atributo* en cada uno de ellos del modo siguiente:

```
<input type="button" id="bloque1" value="Mostrar texto 2" onclick="muestra2();">
<input type="button" id="bloque2" value="Mostrar texto 1" onclick="muestra1();">
```

Al final a tu código lo podemos dejar como:

- Inicialmente al div completo que contiene al segundo botón y texto colócale un display none que después mediante JS modificaremos
- Obtienes las dos secciones que representan a los divs así como los 2 botones
- A cada botón le añades un listener en el evento click y solo modificas a los divs correspondientes según sea el caso pasándolos de none a block
- Es un punto de partida para sacar el llamado a la función de las etiquetas HTML lo cual se hace un tanto invasivo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     </head>
        <style>
          .bloque2 {
            display: none;
          }
        </style>
     <body>
    
      <h3>Cambiar texto y botón</h3>
      <hr>
      <div class="bloque1">Texto 1
       <input type="button" id="bloque1" value="Mostrar texto 2">
      </div>
    
      <div class="bloque2">Texto 2
       <input type="button" id="bloque2" value="Mostrar texto 1">
      </div>
    <script>
    let boton2  = document.getElementById("bloque1")
    let boton1  = document.getElementById("bloque2")
    let bloque1 = document.querySelector(".bloque1")
    let bloque2 = document.querySelector(".bloque2")
    
    boton2.addEventListener("click", () => {
      bloque1.style.display = "none"
      bloque2.style.display = "block"
    })
    
    boton1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      bloque1.style.display = "block"
      bloque2.style.display = "none"
    })
    </script>
     </body>
    
    </html>
```